# Предотвратить повторную отправку формы

Tags: php, redbeanphp

КАК предотвратить повторную отправку формы.

```
<?php
require 'resource/libs/db/db.php';

$data = $_POST;
if(isset($data['do-signup']))
{
    $errors = array();
    if(trim($data['login']) == '')
    {
        $errors[]='Введите логин';
    }
    if(trim($data['email']) == '')
    {
        $errors[]='Введите email';
    }
    if($data['password'] == '')
    {
        $errors[]='Введите pasw';
    }
    if(R::count('users',"login = ?", array($data['login'])) > 0 )
    {
            $errors[] = 'login уже есть';
    }
    if(R::count('users',"email = ?", array($data['email'])) > 0 )
    {
            $errors[] = 'email уже есть';
    }

    if(empty($errors))
    {
            $user = R::dispense('users');
            $user->login = $data['login'];
            $user->email = $data['email'];
            $user->password = password_hash($data['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            R::store($user);
    }else
    {
        echo '<div>'.array_shift($errors).'</div><hr>';

    }
}?>

<form action="signup.php" method="POST">
            <ul>
            <li><input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин"></li>
            <li><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Пароль"></li>
            <li><input type="submit" name="do-signup" value="Вход"></li>
        </ul>
        </form>
```

Comment: Не отправлять повторно.
Если вы имеете в виду повторную отправку через F5 - тогда нужно делать редирект. Если вы имеете в виду невозможность  повторки отправки на  фронте - тогда javascript вам в помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вас спасет самый древний костыль на эту тему, дедовский способ:

В форме вставляем:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo(rand(1,999999));?>" />
```

Тогда проверка выглядит так:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['token'])) {
    if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['formToken']) {
        // ошибка: повторная отправка формы
    } else {
        $_SESSION['formToken'] = $_POST['token'];
        // обрабатываем форму
    }
}
```

---

Редирект (но тогда от выводов в PHP придется отказаться)

```
header("Location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Comment: Увы, но не помогает

Comment: @ARTUS от чего не помогает?

Comment: @ARTUS дедовские способы всегда работают. Значит вы что-то не так делаете

Comment: Я попробовал сделать так как вы мне рекомендовали, но все-ровно вылазит окно в котором написано    ( Чтобы отобразить эту страницу, Firefox должен отправить информацию для повторения ранее произведённого действия (например, запрос на поиск или онлайн-покупка). )

Comment: Но type="hidden" , input становиться невидемым

Comment: @ARTUS Ну то что окно вылазиет это нормально, вы жмете ОК и ничего не должно происходить. Если вы хотите чтобы и этого окна не было, тогда добавлю в ответ пример редиректа, но это плохой способ

Comment: Хорошо, Спасибо

Comment: Да снял, просто не помогло, но вроде бы работает

Comment: я просто узнал, ничего страшного

Comment: Спасибо, странно , но работает

Comment: @ARTUS яж говорил, дедовские способы всегда работают.

Comment: И я бы хотел у вас узнать, как  создать админку, то-есть когда я в хожу в свой аккаунт у меня появляеться привелегии. Надеюсь понятно обьяснил

Comment: @ARTUS я даже не знаю как вам объяснить-то так правильно и доступно, возможно лучше вам создать еще один вопрос чтоб вам помогли с теорией. А от меня: каждую привилегию надо создавать вручную, собсна в процессе создания вы поймете как ей управлять, а если поймете как ей управлять, то не составит труда это управление сделать на определенных лиц.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь